# Question about hping3, TCP and ngrok

Tags: ip, denial-of-service, tcp, iot

I have set up a experimental setup which consists of:

- Windows PC with ethernet cable;
- Arduino shield (connected to Windows machine with USB) with LTE
  connectivity sending data using TCP/IP to ngrok;
- VirtualBox with Kali Linux running on same Windows machine mentioned
  above;

On Kali Linux there is working Python script for receiving local TCP packets and ngrok TCP tunnel forwarding packets sent from Arduino to my local TCP server. Everything works fine and I'm getting correct data on Python console.

After this I wanted to test my system with DoS attack. On same Kali VirtualBox machine I used tool called hping3. If I type "hping3 -S --flood --rand-source Arduino_shield_IP" connection is dropped and python console doesnt recieve any data until I stop TCP flood. But when I run same python script and ngrok on another laptop, connection isnt dropped when TCP flooding. Why is that? I got devices IP adress using AT commands.

I have to mention that this is a university project and we have a permission to test LTE like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you saturate the communication path between the VM and the shield when doing the DoS from inside the VM. Since that's the same path you use for your TCP connection it will heavily impact the delivery of data inside TCP connection, i.e. your Python console hangs.

If you do instead the DoS from outside the VM the communication path between the shield and the VM is not affected by the DoS. Additionally I expect that less bandwidth will be used by the DoS since the connection from the different notebook (via LTE?) provides less usable bandwidth than the local connection between VM and shield. This will also take load from the shield.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. Thats likely the case. Do you have any tips on how to execute DoS attack from outside the local network?

Comment: *"Do you have any tips on how to execute DoS attack from outside the local network?"* - No, and this is also a different (and very broad) question than your original one and should thus be asked (with more focus to be less broad) as a new question.